# How To: Fetch profile information using hammock with linkedin oauth

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, linkedin-api, hammock

How do I get profile information of the authorized user, using Hammock https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock

This is the call to get the profile default profile information https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~

So far I've been unsuccessful, sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here: http://mrsarker.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/linkedin-rest-api-in-asp-net-mvc/

The sample code helped me resolve my issue.